# EXCEL 2007 SENDKEYS Ambiguous name detected

Tags: excel, sendkeys, ambiguous

I am trying to hide the ribbon in excel 2007 via vba with the following code:

```
If Application.CommandBars("Ribbon").Height > 59 Then Application.SendKeys ("^{F1}"), True
```

But Office help window opens up and says something like "Ambiguous name detected".
Amy ideas what is wrong ?

Comment: With the exception of using `SendKeys()` (Something I would avoid) I don't see anything wrong with that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to have anything to do with that line of code.

Ambiguous name detected usually means that you have 2 subs or functions with the same name